# Python, using a comparison function for finding the best object

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have a function that takes as parameters 2 objects: `a` and `b`
The function checks (with a very long algorithm) which one of these objects is better.

If a is better it returns -1, if b is better it returns 1, if they tied it returns 0

My problem is:

I have 21 of these objects in a list.

I need to find out, using the function above (the function cannot be
changed, the only way is to compare 2 objects, it's a very complicated
and long algorithm), which one of these 21 objects is the best.

I tried thinking for hours how to do it efficiently without doing the same comparison too many times, how to write an algorithm that will find out which one is the best (and if two of them are tied and they both are the best, it doesn't matter which one to take, though I don't think it's even possible for a tie to happen), and I couldn't come up with anything good.

The function's name is `handCompare(a, b)`
The objects are found in a list called `Combos`, `len(combos)` is 21
I need an algorithm that will find out the best item in the combos list

Thanks for reading and I hope you can help :)

Comment: What is wrong with using your function to implement the ordering methods (`__gt__()`, `__lt__()`, `__eq__()`) and then using `list.sort()`?

Comment: What do you mean? Did you understand my problem? how is sorting relevant?

Comment: If you sort the items using your comparison, the last item will be the best.

Comment: Hmmm haven't thought of that, what would be the python syntax to do it?

Comment: I already explained, although [`user545424`'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10957504/722121) is more apt if you only want this one result.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I do want only one result.

Comment: In your comparison algorithm, is it always true that if `a < b` and `b < c` then `a < c` for some objects `a`, `b`, and `c`?

Comment: Yes, their "goodness" could be expressed by numbers, the higher the better (it isn't but it could, so yes what you asked is true)

Comment: @OmerPT: Then, using any O(nlogn) sorting algorithm (such as Timsort) should help you minimize the number of comparisons made.

Answer (score 8):

This will work if you change `hand_compare()` to return `1` if a is better and `-1` if b is better.

```
import functools
best = max(combos, key=functools.cmp_to_key(hand_compare))
```

Comment: it should be min() due to `hand_compare(a, b) < 0` if `a` is better

Comment: I don't really get what you did here, copy pasting it didn't work so I need to understand it in order to fix it...
Could you explain it please?

Comment: I think it's pretty self explanatory if you read the docs on [max](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) and [cmp_to_key](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key).

Comment: Works perfectly thanks a lot for your help everybody :) I understand it now

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way: Create an object of each one, with your comparison function as `__cmp__` (python 2.x) or define `__lt__` and `__eq__` (python 3.x).  Stash each one in a list named list_.  Find the least valued one using min(list_).

An optimization that might help, if practical: If you can come up with a way of mapping your objects to (possibly large) integers, such that the integer for x is < the integer for y, iff the original object ox is < the original object oy, and then take a min of the integers.  This should speed things up slightly, if it's workable for your types.